# vDatum returns error at Linux command line - fails to accept parameters with GUI

Tags: ubuntu, datum, vertical-transformation, noaa-vdatum

I am trying convert a GeoTiff using [VDatum](https://vdatum.noaa.gov/welcome.html) at the Linux command line.
My data reference the Washington State Plane South CRS with z values referencing EGM96.  I would like to convert these z values to NAVD88.

Here is my command.

> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar /opt/vdatum/vdatum.jar ihorz:NAD83_2011:spc:ft:4602 ivert:EGM1996:ft:height:GEOID12B ohorz:NAD83_2011:spc:ft:4602 overt:NAVD88:ft:height:GEOID12B -file:geotiff:geotiff,autosrcgeo:/home/gerry/geotiff/2019_1_308_405.tif;/home/gerry/geotiff/results/ region:3

I can confirm that I can run the vDatum GUI from the command line so  I know the paths to java and VDatum.jar are fine.  I know the paths to the geotiff are good.  This is the resulting error message:

> NOAA's Vertical Datum Transformation - v4.1.2

```
System.file.separator= /
System.path.separator= :

cmdargs  :[Ljava.lang.String;@3930015a
12:37:13 : [vdatum_command]: java.lang.NumberFormatException
For input string: "/home/gerry/geotiff/2019_1_308_405.tif"

bash: /home/gerry/geotiff/results/: Is a directory
```

I do not understand why I would get a NumberFormatException on a file path string.

Thinking I would try to do the conversion manually I started the VDatum GUI.

Trouble with the GUI is that if I enter EGM96 for the input vertical datum, I get a pop-up claiming I need to reset the horizontal CRS.  If I reset the CRS to NAD83_2011 the vertical datum input reverts to NAVD88.  At the GUI vDatum will not accept the data vertical and horizontal values.

Thinking there might be a bug for the GUI Linux version of vDatum tried the input arguments at the online verson of vDatum. Online I can set the correct vertical and horizontal values for my input data but there is no geotiff conversion option online.  Now I am unsure if just the GUI version is malfunctioning, my command line is wrong, or if vDatum on Linux just does not work.

How do I use the Linux version of vDatum to convert Washington State Plane South, feet, EGM96 data to the NAVD88 vertical datum?

Answer (score 0):

I did hear back from NOAA about this problem.

Converting GeoTiff format files only works on Windows OS.